# After buying the deluxe version of civ5 on Steam, where is the soundtrack?

Tags: steam, civilization-5

I've checked the media tab on under Library and the purchase email doesn't say anything about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\sid meier's civilization v\Assets\DLC\DLC_Deluxe\Soundtrack

Obviously, replace "C:\Program Files" with whatever directory you installed Steam in.

[Source](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1439238)

Comment: Works great for me. On 64 bit Windows 7, Steam defaults to Program Files (x86), so...
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\sid meier's civilization v\Assets\DLC\DLC_Deluxe\Soundtrack`