# Civ V GOTY edition soundtrack download on Mac

Tags: steam, civilization-5, macos

Where does the Game Of The Year edition Civilization V soundtrack get downloaded on Mac?  I looked at [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7974/after-buying-the-deluxe-version-of-civ5-on-steam-where-is-the-soundtrack) and from it deduced that the equivalent location on the Mac would be `~/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/sid meier's civilization v/assets/DLC/DLC_Deluxe` but this directory didn't contain a soundtrack directory.

Any ideas where I should be looking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have Steam, a Mac, and I own the Deluxe edition of Civ 5 that I got for Windows, so I thought I'd go digging around to see if I could find the soundtrack.

The directory you mention on my install contains a Soundtrack directory, in addition to Sounds, Gameplay, Behind the Scenes, and the Babylon Expansion files.

> /Users/{username}/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/sid meier's civilization v/Assets/DLC/DLC_Deluxe

You might try right clicking on the game in your Steam library, and then click "View Downloadable Content" to see if you have "Civ V Digital Deluxe Content (Mac)" as one of your DLC packages.  I pre-ordered the Deluxe edition for Windows, and got the Mac version via SteamPlay after that became a feature of Steam, so that might be a factor.

Previously I found another method of extracting the soundtrack, which you can find below:

---

I checked around and I found [this thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1606514) on the Steam forums.  It appears to have a sections of interest:

> You can access the soundtrack files directly from the game contents. Mine were here:
>
> /Users/{username}/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/sid meier's civilization v/assets/Sounds/Streamed/Music/

You'll have to use the Finder to get to this directory, and then you can copy these files out, which are in .ogg format.

Comment: No sign of the Civ V Digital Deluxe Content DLC, so I'm thinking it didn't download.  I've uninstalled and am reinstalling to see if that helps.  If that doesn't then I guess the next stop is steam support.  Thanks for the help

Comment: @GordonM, Some of the people in that thread (where I found the alternate method, see the link) seemed to think that if you bought the Mac edition of Civ V you don't get the Deluxe content regardless, since there technically isn't a Deluxe edition of Civ V for Mac.  I don't know how accurate this is.  I think your plan of contacting Steam Support if reinstalling doesn't work is good.

Comment: @GordonM: I'm having the same issue.  Did reinstalling help?  (I just contacted Steam Support, too.)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Mac-only users appear to be out of luck re: the Soundtrack for now.

I bought the Game of the Year edition on my mac, and did not find a Soundtrack in the DLC_Deluxe folder as agent86 suggested I would.

I contacted Steam Support, and they told me the Soundtrack folder would be in the same location as the agent86's answer said.  After telling them it wasn't there, someone else replied:

> My apologies however it would appear that the soundtrack is currently not available on the Mac at this time.
>
> You may install this game on PC to gain access to the soundtrack.
>
> We apologize for the inconvenience this issue has caused.

I don't understand why they don't just make the files available to Mac clients, but that's how it is right now.

Answer (score 0):

from terminal:

```
# cd ~/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/Sid Meier's Civilization V/Civilization V.app/Contents/Home/assets/Sounds/Streamed/Music

# mkdir ~/Desktop/CivVSoundtrack

# find ./ -name '*.ogg' -exec cp {} ~/Desktop/CivVSoundtrack/ \;
```